# pass current element to onclick event within a setAttribute call

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a bunch of anchor tags in a `for` loop, using the javascript `createElement` function, like this

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
```

I want to add an `onclick` event handler to each anchor element, that passes the clicked element to a function, like this

```
anchor.setAttribute("onclick","app.activateAnchor("+this+")");
```

which didn't work.

So I tried the following

```
anchor.setAttribute("onclick","app.activateAnchor(this)");
```

which also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  I'm an idiot.

As @Cheery points out in a comment below, my second solution actually does work.  I had simply implemented it incorrectly on my first attempt.

Comment: `anchor.onclick = app.activateAnchor(this);`

Comment: Second method should also work. But function `app.activateAnchor` should be `visible` - within the scope. http://jsfiddle.net/kzug3b18/

Comment: thanks @Cheery - you were correct!  the second solution did work, i had just implemented it incorrectly the first time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This,

```
anchor.onclick = function () { app.activateAnchor(this); }
```

Usually you should assign function reference to event handler.

```
anchor.onclick = app.activateAnchor
```

Comment: `anchor.onclick = app.activateAnchor(this);` is very wrong and should rather be `anchor.onclick = function() { app.activateAnchor(this); };`

Comment: @FelixKling thats exactly I quoted in answer.

Comment: Kind of yeah, but why are you even suggesting it if it is wrong?

Comment: @FelixKling updated...I have a great respect towards you master.